# Como crear una sublista de una lista usando un Bucle While Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucles, while

Tengo que crear una función, que tome como parámetro una lista, y dentro de la función debo crear una sublista con los mismos valores de la lista que pasé como parámetro, hasta que llegue al número 5, sin incluirlo.

Si esta fuese la función:

```
def sublist(list1):
    pass
print(sublist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
```

El output debería ser algo así:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
def sublist(list1):
    sublist1 = []
    idx = 0
    l = list1[idx]
    while idx < 4:
        sublist1.append(l)
        idx += 1
    return sublist1


print(sublist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
```

Y me genera esto de output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Me está agregando a la sublista que hice solo el primer valor de la lista original, pero 4 veces.

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que siempres estas asignado el mismo elemento en cada iteración:

```
   l = list1[idx]
   while idx < 4:
       sublist1.append(l)
```

Debería ser:

```
   while idx < 4:
       l = list1[idx]
       sublist1.append(l)
```

Pero resulta más simple usando rebanado de listas:

```
def sublist(lista):
    return lista[:4]
```